# No sound and no network connection in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I changed the permission of /usr today. So stupid. Then I went into recovery mode and changed the permission back. But after that, there are no sound and no network connection on my system. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you could add the commands you executed (for the disaster and for the recovery). Anyway, I would start by studying the system logs:

```
$ dmesg  
$ more /var/log/syslog
```

They are usually very useful and can give you some clues about what is really happening.